# Mongoose save not actually saving model, even with markModified

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have tried searching for a solution for nearly 2 hours and am unable to fix my code. I've updated my schema for user accounts and want to save new values.

I am using findOne so that I can verify fields exist/don't exist before saving, but if there is a better method using update, please let me know.

#### Updating profile

```
            User.findOne({ 'local.userID': userID }, function(err, user) {

            // checks if their discord ID is undefined
           if (user.local.newDiscordID == undefined) {

                user.local.newDiscordID = message.author.id;
                user.local.newVerifiedStatus = true;

                user.markModified('local');
                user.markModified('local.newDiscordID');
                user.markModified('local.newVerifiedStatus');

                user.save(function(err, res) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    } else {
                        console.log(`Activated ${user.local.email}.`);
                    }
                });

            };
```

#### Schema

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
local: {
    email: String,
    password: String,
    userID: String,
    newDiscordID: String,
    newVerifiedStatus: String,
}
```

At first, I was trying to insert an entire new object and figured that's why my code wasn't working, so I removed that section and tried only updating the newDiscordID and the newVerifiedStatus fields, yet it still does not work.

Any ideas?